# What can cause an element selector to be applied instead of an important class selector?

Tags: css

To the best of my understanding an element selector (`h2`) has a specificity value `0001`, while two class selectors (`.styleguide .menu-item--active`) have a specificity value `0020`.

- How can the `h2` rule override the `.styleguide .menu-item--active` rule?
- Why does setting the importance flag not work?

[image]

Comment: it seems still some part of css code is missing in your screenshot, if css "!important" is overrided, then there is someother "!important" property exists in the css

Comment: As you can see element.style is on the top, so I have scrolled the list all the way to the top. You can also see that it is the h2 rule that is applied as it is not striked through. There are more CSS rules below the captured image, but those should not be relevant as far as I know. Let me know if you need more information to answer the question.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? This screenshot is not enough to nail down the problem. Although the "inherited from" sounds suspicious; are you sure the h2 has the class `menu-item--active`?

Comment: are those classes applied to the h2 element or to its parent?

Comment: @MrLister: You nailed it. That style is only inherited. I saw the style in the styles tab of the dev tools and did not notice the inherited from marking. I accidentally applied the style to the parent element.

Comment: OK. Then change the selector to `.styleguide .menu-item--active, .styleguide .menu-item--active *` and you're done. And maybe you won't even need `!important`!

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Now when I understand the problem, it was easy to fix it somehow. I fixed it by moving the class from the parent element to the child element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, since you have not provided the html code, but 
in the devtools one can see that orange is inherited from some other element. I guess, that orange it some div's property, while h2's colour is the colour of the element itself. That explains why the output colour is black. If you want the text to be orange, you should specify it for the h2, rather than inherit it from a parent element.